# Using news feed in an app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, mobile

I'm looking to display news from various sources in an iOS app. The trouble is, I can't seem to find anybody other than the BBC who give developers access.

Is there a news source who allows free developer access, obviously with credit provided?

EDIT: There's obviously apps which do similar things to what my app will do, such as Summly. Surely they don't license out the content from all the sources they use?

Comment: I'm not sure using RSS is permitted by most sites' T&Cs.

Answer (score 1):

Parse RSS feeds from various news sources. Example:

http://www.cnn.com/services/rss/

http://www.nbcnews.com/id/24057171/

http://www.foxnews.com/about/rss/

http://www.cbsnews.com/2100-18565_162-666437.html

http://abcnews.go.com/Site/page/rss--3520115

Comment: An example from the CNN usage says "RSS is a free service offered by CNN for non-commercial use.", so surely that would that mean that if i sold my app, i'd be violating that?

Comment: Mmm... perhaps there would be away around it. Use your imagination ;) Or just use the ones that don't have that restriction.

Answer (score 1):

I think many sites would provide RSS as feed. Did you try [yahoo news feed](http://developer.yahoo.com/rss/)?

Comment: "Yahoo! RSS feeds are free of charge for individuals, and non-profit organizations for non-commercial use."

Answer (score 1):

Try these 2:

http://www.prlog.org/free-rss-feeds.html
http://www.feedzilla.com/

You may want to drop feedzilla a note to verify that you can use their product in your app.

Good luck.